# Facebook Like Box Link Color

Tags: css, facebook, hyperlink

I use the Facebook Like Box with the Javascript SDK and my own CSS stylesheet.
The CSS link is [here](http://xaforum.tk/js/facebook.css).
What I want is to change the link color to #D90000 to match my site color. I tried everything but I just displayed like it is. So what should I add to the CSS to change my link colors?
Thanks ;)

Comment: I don't know if this will help but take a lookt at it: http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-your-facebook-fan-box/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Facebook loads its stylesheets dynamically (via a JS call), they'll always end up the last declared styles on the page - as such, you cant override any styles declared in their stylesheets unless you add them to the elements directly. Your stylesheet will work for styles which are not already declared in the facebook stylesheet, but will not override any declarations which are included.

Instead, you need to force your style declarations to take precedence using `!important`:

```
.fan_box .connections_grid .grid_item a:link {color: #D90000 !important; }
.fan_box .connections_grid .grid_item a:active {color: #D90000 !important; }
.fan_box .connections_grid .grid_item a:visited {color: #D90000 !important; }
.fan_box .connections_grid .grid_item a:hover {color: #D90000 !important; }
```

Comment: Technically !important will override, But In my case Its not loading the CSS. Any possible reason and solution.

Comment: @nepsdotin - I'd recommend you open a new question with some more info - not sure that we can help you with the limited info you've provided here.

Answer (score 3):

The facebook like box is loaded from a iframe with its own code. As far as I know it's not possible to modify its classes.

Comment: Of course, that's why I used the Javascript SDK, explained here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/.  
My other CSS edits work, but can't change my link color, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. You can check the CSS file in the OP.

Comment: The JavaScript SDK is still creating iframes.

Answer (score 1):

```
.fan_box .connections_grid .grid_item a:link {color: black; text-decoration: none; }
.fan_box .connections_grid .grid_item a:active {color: black; text-decoration: none; }
.fan_box .connections_grid .grid_item a:visited {color: black; text-decoration: none; }
.fan_box .connections_grid .grid_item a:hover {color: black; text-decoration: none; }
```

You can use all of those to control the various states of the link. Replace color and text-decoration with whatever properties you want.

Edit: made it more specific so it matches your other declarations.

Comment: That's exactly my problem, I've added those lines to my stylesheet, but still the links don't change.
Here is the content of the CSS now: http://xaforum.tk/js/facebook.css